# How to change email sender from power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have created a simple email notification with power automate and I was wondering if we can change the email sender. The email sender is Microsoft Power Apps and Power Automate.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, there is no way to change the "**From**" filed for the **Notification** action in Power Automate.

As a workaround, you can use "**Send an email (V2)**" action to define the email sender. When you click on **Show advanced options**, you’ll see another field, "**From (Send as)**". You can send emails from a **[shared mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/create-a-shared-mailbox?view=o365-worldwide)**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**There’re just two prerequisites:**

- The **shared mailbox** must exist.
- You must have either Send as or Send on behalf permissions to the mailbox.

Here is a good Blog for your reference:

- [3 ways to change email sender address in Power Automate](https://tomriha.com/3-ways-to-change-email-sender-name-in-power-automate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the from field for the Notification action in Power Automate.

As a workaround, you can use the OOB Send Email action. It supports changing the from field (send as). As long as you have access to that mailbox, it will work. I recommend using a shared mailbox with a generic name for these purposes.